# Google BigQuery - regex functions for utf-8

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

```
SELECT  REGEXP_EXTRACT('name=北海道新幹線|gauge=1435|layer=2|usage=main|bridge=yes|', r'layer=(-?[0-9]+)|') AS Layer
```

yield null.  while

```
select  REGEXP_EXTRACT('layer=2|',r'layer=(-?[0-9]+)|') as layer
```

yield the wanted result : 2

I suspect the first one failed due to utf-8 characters?

How to extract layer info for the first string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing `|` is interpreted as OR. You need to escape it with a backslash, e.g.:

```
SELECT  REGEXP_EXTRACT('name=北海道新幹線|gauge=1435|layer=2|usage=main|bridge=yes|', r'layer=(-?[0-9]+)\|') AS Layer
```

Without the backslash, the second example that you have works because the regex is interpreted as the pattern OR the empty string.